# Flutter Undefined name 'context' for localization

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

Any help please how do I pass the context for localization here?
error says: Undefined name 'context'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

```
category1.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myproject/classes/item.dart';
import 'page_details.dart';
import 'package:myproject/classes/language_constants.dart';

List<Item> detailsList = [
  Item(
      name: translation(context).name_1,
      image: 'assets/rivers/object1.jpg',
      details: translation(context).details_1,
      facts: [
        translation(context).fact_1_1,
        translation(context).fact_1_2,
        translation(context).fact_1_3,
      ],
    photolink: '',
    author: '',
    licensetype: '',
    licenselink: '',
  ),
  Item(
      name: translation(context).name_2,
      image: 'assets/rivers/object1.jpg',
      details: translation(context).details_2,
      facts: [
        translation(context).fact_2_1,
        translation(context).fact_2_2,
        translation(context).fact_2_3,
      ],
    photolink: '',
    author: '',
    licensetype: '',
    licenselink: '',
  ),
]
```

tranlation() is defined as follows:

```
language_constants.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

AppLocalizations translation(BuildContext context) {
  return AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
}
```

Class Item is defined as follows:

```
item.dart

class Item {
  final String name;
  final String image;
  final String details;
  final String photolink;
  final String author;
  final String licensetype;
  final String licenselink;
  List<String> facts = <String>[];

  Item({
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
    required this.details,
    required this.facts,
    required this.photolink,
    required this.author,
    required this.licensetype,
    required this.licenselink,
  });
}
```

I pass appropriate class Item as a content via detailsList[index]:

```
category1.dart

ElevatedButton.icon(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
            minimumSize: const Size(30, 30),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            _navigateToPageDetails(context, detailsList[index]);
          },
...
)
```

and MaterialPageRoute():

```
category1.dart

_navigateToPageDetails(BuildContext context, Item item) async {
    await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PageDetails(
          item: item,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And finally the page:

```
page_details.dart

import 'package:myproject/classes/item.dart';

class PageDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final Item item;

  const PageDetails({Key? key, required this.item}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PageDetails> createState() => _PageDetailsState();
}

class _PageDetailsState extends State<PageDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.item.name),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child:Column(
          children: [
            Image.asset(widget.item.image),
            ...
```

So, I don't understand how to pass context to Class Item, so that this simple code doesn't throw the error:

```
translation(context).name_1,
-->
Error: Undefined name 'context'.
```

I've tried to add BuildContext context to the class, but it doesn't help.
I've tried to use widget.context - the same, it doesn't help.
Perhaps Class Item should extend some class? but experimenting with that also doesn't help.

Please help me..

### Update after accepted answer

Following the perfect advice by Saichi Okuma above, I would like to share the code from my app, so that maybe it will be useful for somebody else.

```
Item detailsList(BuildContext context, index) {
  final List<Item> list = [];

  list.addAll([
    Item(
        name: translation(context).name_1,
        image: 'assets/rivers/object1.jpg',
        details: translation(context).details_1,
        facts: [
          translation(context).fact_1_1,
          translation(context).fact_1_2,
          translation(context).fact_1_3,
        ],
      photolink: '',
      author: '',
      licensetype: '',
      licenselink: '',
    ),
    Item(
        name: translation(context).name_2,
        image: 'assets/rivers/object2.jpg',
        details: translation(context).details_2,
        facts: [
          translation(context).fact_2_1,
          translation(context).fact_2_2,
          translation(context).fact_2_3,
        ],
      photolink: '',
      author: '',
      licensetype: '',
      licenselink: '',
    ),
  ]);
  
  final Item element = list[index];

  return element;
}
```

the function above gets the context and returns the required element of class Item.

and then instead of using a list (as in old initial code), I call the method as follows:

```
onPressed: () {
            _navigateToPageDetails(context, detailsList(context, index));
          },
```

Comment: Where in the code is this? `List<Item> detailsList = [...]` ?

Comment: I've added locations of code chunks.

Comment: In short, as I understand it: 'category1.dart' is a page with a content, which is of Class Item.  I pass this content to next page 'page_details.dart'. Everything worked well. And when I changed content text strings with localized params, a context is needed. And I can't understand how to pass it there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no context present when you build your list, that's why you get the error. A simple way to solve, keeping your logic:

```
List<Item> detailsList(BuildContext context) {
  final List<Item> list = [];
  
  list.addAll([
    Item(
        name: translation(context).name_1,
        image: 'assets/rivers/object1.jpg',
        details: translation(context).details_1,
        facts: [
          translation(context).fact_1_1,
          translation(context).fact_1_2,
          translation(context).fact_1_3,
        ],
      photolink: '',
      author: '',
      licensetype: '',
      licenselink: '',
    ),
    Item(
        name: translation(context).name_2,
        image: 'assets/rivers/object1.jpg',
        details: translation(context).details_2,
        facts: [
          translation(context).fact_2_1,
          translation(context).fact_2_2,
          translation(context).fact_2_3,
        ],
      photolink: '',
      author: '',
      licensetype: '',
      licenselink: '',
    ),
  ]);
  
  return list;
}
```

When you request a list, pass the context as argument.